Terminal object in $\infty$-category
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an $\infty$-category.
How to show that the following definitions agree?


An object $X\in\mathcal{C}$ is terminal if the space $\mathrm{Map}_{\mathcal{C}}(Z,X)$ is contractible for all $Z\in \mathcal{C}$.
An object $X\in\mathcal{C}$ is terminal if there exists an equivalence $\mathrm{Map}_{\mathcal{C}}({-},X)\simeq *$, where $*$ is a functor $\mathcal{C}\to \mathcal{S}$ that sends every object in $\mathcal{C}$ to a contractible space.



Presumably $\mathcal S$ is the category of sets?

@ThomasAndrews No, spaces

Put it in the question.

Note that both definitions do not define an initial object, but a terminal object.
Equivalences of functors can be checked pointwise: you always know that there is an essentially unique natural transformation $\mathrm{Map}_\mathcal{C}(-,X)\to *$ since the latter functor is terminal in $\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op},\mathcal{S})$, and this natural transformation is a natural equivalence iff it is objectwise so.

How to define $*$? I am confused about the following: In definition 1, $\mathrm{Map}{\mathcal{C}}(Z,X)$ and $\mathrm{Map}{\mathcal{C}}(Z',X)$ could be different contractible spaces. Must we define $\mathrm{Map}_{\mathcal{C}}(-,X)\to *$ in such a way to keep track of these potential differences?

No, you don't have to define the functor $\colon\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}\to\mathcal{S}$ in such a way to keep track of these potential differences. The point is that if $$ and $*'$ are two contractible spaces, then some random map $A\to *$ is an equivalence iff any other random map $A\to *'$ is an equivalence. In particular, any two functors $\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}\to\mathcal{S}$ that send objects to some contractible spaces are naturally equivalent.

How to see 'if ∗ and ∗′ are two contractible spaces, then some random map →∗ is an equivalence iff any other random map →∗′ is an equivalence.'?

This is either the 2-out-of-3 property or the statement that all contractible spaces are equivalent. For instance, if $A\to *$ is an equivalence, then $A$ is contractible, and therefore $A\to *'$ is an equivalence because any map between contractible spaces is so. This can for instance be seen by looking at homotopy groups.
